# Host not found error while executing copy module

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Ansible version :1.9.4, 1.9.3, 1.9.1,

Using ec2, so specifying pem key in ansible.cfg

I have used Ansible for while, but this error is strange.

Copy module works fine when executing in ad-hoc like the snippet below. The below line is just an example.

```
Ansible instance123 -m copy - a "src= dest= mode ="
```

But gives "host not found" while executing the same module in playbook.

The playbook:

```
  ---
 - hosts: all
   sudo: yes
   tasks:
    - name: copy
      copy: src=./ansible.cfg dest=/home/ubuntu/ mode=0644
```

I checked command module both in playbooks and trying it in ad-hoc also. That works fine. I found that version 1.8.2 had this error, and I tried all state versions of 1.9.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting and the part of the playbook/role that is giving the error?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have uploaded a sample playbook. I tried the same playbook with many modules like service module for restarting the tomcat, where all work except copy module. The module works like a charm in ad-hoc but fails with a lame error "host not found". Other tasks in the play gets executed like "service, debug". Moreover, i cross checked copy.py in ansible, that doesn't contain any "module.failjson stating host not found". so quite confused.

Comment: I'm somewhat inclined to vote to close this question as "typo" - the answer given is undoubtedly the solution in this case, but it doesn't bear any connection to the question, and thus I am not sure how readers could learn from it for their own cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was a var named `inventory_hostname`. So this was the var that was conflicting.